# Enable alias to work

Tags: bash

I add two alias to `~/.bashrc`

```
    # add some helpful aliases
    alias l.='ls -d .* --color=auto'
    alias ll='ls -l --color=auto'
```

However,they not work

```
    $ l.
    bash: l.: command not found
    $ ll
    bash: ll: command not found
```

The Path is

```
    $ echo $PATH
    /Users/g/bin:me/Users/me/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/me/bin:/Users/me/.rvm/bin
```

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Did you start a new shell session after modifying `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: `source  ~/.bashrc`

Comment: You two must know something that I don't because I've only ever had to `source` when updating the path `.bash_profile`. For as far back as I can remember, `bash` or closing and exiting and opening a new terminal has always been sufficient and that's across multiple environments.

Comment: source is perfectly fine when you want to execute the commands in your current shell. Closing your terminal is fine when you don't care about what you have been doing in that current shell.

Comment: I would assume that someone would take that into account before start a new session but I've updated my answer to include your point.

Comment: It refuse to work when I start a new session. @GillesQuenot

Comment: What says `echo $SHELL` ?

Comment: $ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
@GillesQuenot

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is nothing running in the session that you need, after setting the alias, enter `bash` or close the terminal and reopen to start a new session. Your alias will work afterwards.

Tested and confirmed with my environments.

Answer (score 0):

The file ~/.bashrc is read only once, when a bash shell starts. To activate your aliases you must instruct bash to reread the file with the following command.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

An even shorter, although more cryptic, version of this command is the following.

```
. ~/.bashrc
```